# I do not see the Java image when I tried to create a maven jlink

Tags: java, maven, jlink

I create a simple project where I want to create windows image. I have a maven project with maven-jlink-plugin. I am using Netbeans and Widows 10. When I create the image it looks like fine but I do not see the .bath file.

```
        <artifactId>maven-jlink-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <strinpDebug>true</strinpDebug>
                <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
               
                <jlinkImageName>hello</jlinkImageName>
                <mainClass>com.todlist.testingapp.HelloWorld</mainClass>
                <noManPages>true</noManPages>
            </configuration>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xSyI.jpg)

can someone know which is the error or what I need to fix/change?

Comment: What kind of `bat` file do you expect?

Comment: When I do that process with Maven JavaFX project I can create a hello.bat which with double click runs the app. I want to do something like that with that no JavaFX project.

Comment: Hm..where should the `bat` file coming from? Who should create that?

Comment: For example I creted a JavaFx project where it creates the Java Jlink image with the bat file I can run in wondows to open the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the configuration part to become like this:

```
<configuration>
   <launcher>FILENAME=ARTIFACTID/PACKAGE.MAINCLASS</launcher> 
</configuration>
```

Where
FILENAME is the name of the launcher file you want
ARTIFACTID is the artifactId of your maven module
PACKAGE is the package where your main class is located
MAINCLASS is the name of your main class

Example:
you have a module with the artifact ID *Prototype*, a main class called *Program* in a package called *com.test.main*, and you want a *hello.bat* file as your launcher, you get:
hello=Prototype/com.test.main.Program